# Tumbleweed questions

Tags: discussion

If someone asked a question with no votes, no answers, no comments, and low views, what would he think about ?

The question is too trivial or stupid

The question is misplaced and unintelligible

The question is too general

The question relates to a subject of no interest

The question is too difficult

I have a question of this kind in [Von Neumann and Hausdorff continuous dimensions are related?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1012241/von-neuman-and-hausdorff-continuous-dimensions-are-related)

Comment: "what would he think" That the question asks any potential answerer to get and read von Neuman's book "Continuous Geometry" before they can answer, and that it might not be such a good idea to require this.

Answer (score 5):

The Tumbleweed badge means that hardly anyone looked at the question, and nobody expressed any opinion on it. For this very reason, the badge-issuing software cannot give you an explanation of why this happened, since there is no human input to work with.

Let me rate the likelihood of the Tumbleweed reasons you stated:

1. too trivial or stupid? Not likely. Math.SE *loves* trivial and stupid questions.
2. misplaced and unintelligible? Very likely. I would state this as *mistagged* and *lacking background information*.
3. too general? Not likely. If the question is clearly too broad, someone will either say it or vote to close.
4. relates to a subject of no interest? Could be. Continuous geometries of von Neumann are not such a hot topic.
5. too difficult? By itself this wouldn't be an issue. A focused, clearly stated, interesting question that turns out to be very difficult may end up unanswered but is likely to be upvoted.

Since I think that reason 2 applies to your question, I edited it to include a non-book reference to continuous geometries, and added tags [geometric-measure-theory](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/geometric-measure-theory) and [lattice-order](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lattice-order). Will this help? We'll see

---

I think the concepts are unrelated, but I am not familiar with vN stuff enough to post an answer.

Comment: "Math.SE loves trivial/stupid questions". I wholeheartedly agree even though I wish it wasn't true.+1